# Slow solution of Schrödinger equation

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning

I'm solving non-stationary Schrödinger equation with time-dependent potential `V`:

```
L = 64 \[Pi];
V[L_, t_, x_] := -Sin[\[Pi] t/L] HeavisideTheta[L - t] Sin[x];
Plot3D[V[L, t, x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {t, 0, 2 L}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 30]

ssl = NDSolveValue[{I D[u[t, x], t] == -D[u[t, x], x, x]/2 + 0.1 V[L, t, x]*u[t, x], u[0, x] == Cos[x/2], u[t, -\[Pi]] == 0, u[t, \[Pi]] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 2 L}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6]
```

The parameter `L` is supposed to be really big but the problem is the solution time becomes quite substantial. What is the fastest way to solve this equation in Mathematica?

FYI: You can visualize the results

```
Plot3D[{Im[ssl[t, x]], Re[ssl[t, x]]}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {t, 0, 2 L}, PlotPoints -> 70]
```

And see if the particle goes to a higher energy states due to applying `V`

```
vl = DEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x], {x}], DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, True]}, u[x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 4]
Abs[NIntegrate[ssl[\[Lambda], x]/\[Pi] vl[[2]], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]]
```

Comment: If you're interesting in taking the scenic route, I wrote a book on this topic: https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7050 (available also as hardcover: https://www.amazon.com/Using-Mathematica-Quantum-Mechanics-Students/dp/9811375879/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?keywords=using+mathematics+for+quantum+mechanics%3A+a+student%27s+manual )

Comment: You can try to implement the [split-operator method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-step_method) also see [here](https://www.algorithm-archive.org/contents/split-operator_method/split-operator_method.html)